# ruby constant scope inside a class << self block

Tags: ruby, scope, private

Given a ruby class like

```
class Thing
  class << self
    NUM = 3

    def speak
      NUM.times { puts "Hi!" }
    end
  end
end
```

I can't access `Thing::NUM` from outside the class. If changed to

```
class Thing
  NUM = 3
  class << self
    def speak
      NUM.times { puts "Hi!" }
    end
  end
end
```

`Thing.speak` still works as expected, but I also now have access to `Thing::NUM`. I know the `class << self` idiom opens up the object's singleton class, but I'm confused why such defined class methods are publicly accessible but constants are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must reference the correct class:

```
Thing.singleton_class::NUM #=> 3
```

There is no inconsistency between the way constants and methods in the singleton class are referenced:

```
Thing.methods.include?(:speak)                          #=> true 
Thing.singleton_class.methods.include?(:speak)          #=> false
Thing.singleton_class.instance_methods.include?(:speak) #=> true
```

Answer (score -1):

> I'm confused why such defined class methods are publicly accessible but constants are not.

What makes you think they aren't?

```
class Thing
  class << self
    NUM = 3
  end
end

Thing.singleton_class::NUM
# => 3
```

The constant is defined within the scope of the singleton class of `Thing`, so that's where you access it, in exactly the same way that you access a constant that is defined inside `Thing`.

Just think about it logically: if you define a constant `BAR` inside of the class `Foo`, you access it with `Foo::BAR`. If you define a constant `BAR` inside of the class `Qux`, you access it with `Qux::BAR`. If you define a constant `BAR` inside of the singleton class of `Foo`, you access it with … ???